# Replacing String parts

Tags: java, html, string, replace

this topic has been discussed here a lot, but none of the solution worked for me. I want to replace part of a string, which I got from HTML. Getting and displaying the HTML works fine, but I cann't remove any parts of the string. It acts as it doesn't find it.

Please, have a look at the code bellow:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

public static String URL = "";
public static String htmlString;
public TextView mainText;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);

    constructURL();
    getHtml();

    htmlString.replaceAll("<head>", "hulo");

    mainText.setText(htmlString);
}

public void getHtml() {
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()
                    )
            );
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            htmlString += line + "\n";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public void constructURL() {
    Time time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();
    String year = convertToString(time.year - 2000);
    String month = convertToString(time.month + 1);
    String monthDay = convertToString(time.monthDay);

    URL = "http://www.gymzl.cz/bakalari/suplovani_st/tr" + year + month + monthDay + ".htm";
}

public String convertToString(int value) {
    String text = "";
    if(value < 10) text = "0";
    text += String.valueOf(value);
    return text;
}
}
```

The 'hulo' replacement doesn't seem to work.

I am sorry for such a long code, but I have tried everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replaceAll` does not update the calling string, you need to assign it back. Change this

```
htmlString.replaceAll("<head>", "hulo");
```

to

```
htmlString = htmlString.replaceAll("<head>", "hulo");
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have read the JavaDOC. Sorry about that. I'll mark this as an anwser asap.

Comment: @ViliX No problem, sometime it happens. Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
 htmlString.replaceAll("<head>", "hulo");
```

returns *replaced* string but don't change htmlString

So directle do it like this

```
mainText.setText(""+htmlString.replaceAll("<head>", "hulo"));
```

Answer (score 1):

after calling replaceAll , it will return the replaced string. you need to assign this new string to some object again

like below, assigning it to htmlString again

```
htmlString = htmlString.replaceAll("<head>", "hulo");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mainText.setText(htmlString.replaceAll("<head>", "hulo"));
```